# How Do I Make A Dynamic PHP Link 'No-Follow'?

Tags: seo, php, nofollow

I want to make the Footer links on my website 'No Follow'. How would I do it on these dynamic PHP links?

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="<?=site_url('terms');?>">Terms</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="<?=site_url('privacy');?>">Privacy</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="<?=site_url('disclaimer');?>">Disclaimer</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="<?=site_url('contact');?>">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just for your information, add `rel="nofollow"` attribute to links to _The Terms_ or _Privacy_ is a bad idea. These pages are important for your website and there is no reason why you don't trust on your own webpages.

Comment: I agree, bad idea to use nofollow on internal pages generally, its kinda early 2000's when people tried to shape internal PR flow and nowadays Google dislikes this, furthermore nofollow doesn't mean that these pages won't get indexed. Google follows nofollow links one level, and there after it won't index.

Comment: I was watching an SEOMoz video about footer links and this was their suggestion. I assume it's okay to still add no-follow to save 'link juice' as long as I don't add 'no-index' to them too? Or am I totally wrong here? My most popular pages according to WMT are Terms, Privacy etc which is worrying.

Comment: The important point is, adding nofollow to a link doesn't save any 'link juice'. This is something Google changed a few years ago to prevent what was called 'page rank sculpting'. nofollow is for links you don't trust, it was created primarily to combat comment spam. So like Zistoloen said, there's no reason to use it on your own links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="<?=site_url('terms');?>" rel="nofollow">Terms</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="<?=site_url('privacy');?>" rel="nofollow">Privacy</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="<?=site_url('disclaimer');?>" rel="nofollow">Disclaimer</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="<?=site_url('contact');?>" rel="nofollow">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

The fact that the URL is dynamic is irrelevant, as the rel attribute is separate.